# Image background recognition

Tags: image-processing, pattern-recognition

I want to detect regions on image, kind of clusterize it. The main purpose is to say "this is sky", "this is forest", and a few other patterns (about 10-15).

Now I have prototype for nature recognition, which uses HSV color distance.
So, sky pattern has its approximate HSV range, and for this photo it's detected such way:
[image: original image]

[image: recognized sky]

**But except of sky, forest, water, snow I'd like to recognize clothes, furniture etc.**

How to detect sweater on this photo (it has specific texture of tiny 3-5 pixel squares):
[image]

Except of HSV, I know clustering (e.g. k-means), also worked with FFT for image convolution (they say FFT can be used for feature detection: lines, patterns).
I've heard about image descriptors (SIFT ?), but didn't work with anything related to them, so don't have intuitive understanding.

*Important: This should be fast and have low-memory usage, maybe with no-ideal quality. :) 
When detecting features in real-time, I don't have ability to store large database of tagged images.*

Which methods would you suggest using?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The question is too broad. The problem you mention is called Scene Labelling and is actually a quite complex one. I believe only HSV/any color features wont give you results good enough (at least, not for a wide variety of pictures). Even if you cannot store a large database of tagged images because you want it real-time, you can always train an algorithm in a known database, and then apply the inference in real-time.

Comment: @imaluengo: As I've just read Scene Labelling means use of neural networks. So, is it possible to:
1. create training set (e.g. size = 400 images)
2. build neural network which will retrieve some kind of coefficients for each pattern class
3. store that coefficients in some file, and just use them in real-time.

Emm... And how does the use of NN in this case differ from using classifiers (I worked with AdaBoost) ?

Comment: A NN with HSV features wont give you much better performance. But a Convolutional Neural Network (CNN) will extract multi-scale features with *convolutions of filter banks*, which are much more discriminative features than raw HSV colors ([example paper](http://jmlr.org/proceedings/papers/v32/pinheiro14.pdf)). So yes 1) create a database (or use existing ones), 2) train the CNN in that database, 3) apply the CNN inference in real time. A simpler option would be: segment the image with [superpixels](http://ivrl.epfl.ch/research/superpixels) and then classify each of the superpixels.

Comment: If you really want to detect background, then look for papers about *saliency detection*.